# Is VS what's the name of the dropdowns with classes, functions, etc under the tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu

I am developing an extension, and I need to read the value
of these two dropdowns, but I don't know what they are called.
Any idea or guess?

[alt text http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/992/namea.jpg](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/992/namea.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How to: Navigate and Search in Visual C# Express* in MSDN Library (local) at ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/dv_csexpresscon/html/02412643-f727-4960-bf25-7ef80bda8b25.htm

The **Navigation bar** consists of two combo boxes named **Types** and **Members** displayed at the top of the **Code Editor**...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the names of the combos but the bar they're both in is called the `Navigation Bar` I think.